# Display attachments by ID in a wp.media frame

Tags: uploads, javascript, media, backbone

I'm trying to use the new wp.media uploader frame for an app I'm building. I've read up a lot on other questions, blog posts, etc etc.

The code I pasted below is working already quite fine and even does some extra stuff that I left in for reference in case it's useful to anyone.

But there is one modification I'd like to bring to it: when the frame is opened, **I want it to filter the "media library" display to only show attachment defined by a list of IDs that I provide.**

Here is my current code:

```
// Uploading files
 var file_frame;

 $('.upload_attachments_button').on('click', function( event ){

event.preventDefault();

// If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
if ( file_frame ) {
  file_frame.open();
  return;
}

// Create the media frame.
file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
  title: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_title' ),
  button: { text: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_button_text' ) },
  library : { type : 'image' },
  multiple: true  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
});

   // When frame is open, select existing image attachments from custom field
file_frame.on( 'open', function() {

var selection = file_frame.state().get('selection');
var attachment_ids = jQuery('#attachment_ids').val().split(',');

// This is my attempt at showing only attachment with ID 275 --> but doesn't work!
file_frame.state().set( 'library', media.query({ id: 275 }) );

attachment_ids.forEach(function(id) {
  attachment = wp.media.attachment(id);
  attachment.fetch();
  selection.add( attachment ? [ attachment ] : [] );
});
 });

  // When images are selected, place IDs in hidden custom field and show thumbnails.
file_frame.on( 'select', function() {

var selection = file_frame.state().get('selection');

// Place IDs in custom field
var attachment_ids = selection.map( function( attachment ) {
  attachment = attachment.toJSON();
  return attachment.id;
}).join();
if( attachment_ids.charAt(0) === ',' ) { attachment_ids = attachment_ids.substring(1); }
$('#attachment_ids').val( attachment_ids );


// Show Thumbs
var attachment_thumbs = selection.map( function( attachment ) {
  attachment = attachment.toJSON();
  if( attachment.id != '' ) { return '<img src="' + attachment.sizes.thumbnail.url + '" id="id-' + attachment.id + '" />'; }
}).join(' ');
$('#images-feedback').show();
$('#thumbs').html(attachment_thumbs);

});

// Finally, open the modal
file_frame.open();
});


 // Place selected thumbnail ID into custom field to save as featured image 
 $(document).on('click', '#thumbs img', function() {
 $('#thumbs img').removeClass('chosen');
 var thumb_ID = $(this).attr('id').substring(3);
 $('#wpuf_featured_img').val(thumb_ID);
 $(this).addClass('chosen');
 });
```

I'm attempting to filter the media library display as seen here, but it gives no results:

```
file_frame.state().set( 'library', media.query({ id: 275 }) );
```

Does anyone know how to write the syntax?

Comment: Please post your solution if you have one, I'd be really curious to see it.

Answer (score 3):

You can always filter on the client side:

```
var query = wp.media.query();

query.filterWithIds = function(ids) {
    return _(this.models.filter(function(c) { return _.contains(ids, c.id); }));
};

var res = query.filterWithIds([6,87]); // change these to your IDs

res.each(function(v){
    console.log( v.toJSON() );
});
```

**Disclaimer:** found the beautiful `filterWithIds` function in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442689/backbone-js-how-do-i-filter-a-collection-of-objects-by-an-array-of-model-ids).

Comment: dalbaeb, the code looks amazing. I tried pasting it into the section that runs on "open" of the frame but there is no effect. Should I rewrite the way I am creating the frame altogether by creating a new collection as seen in the example you quoted?

Comment: It was just an example of how to fetch what you need, I didn't intend it to fit right into your code. It all depends on what `file_frame.state().set()` function accepts. You'd ideally paste my code before that line and try to feed what you get out of `query.filterWithIds()` into your `set()` call.

Comment: It seems to me that this is no longer relevant. It didn't work for me as soon as I tried it.

Comment: Well it's from 2013. Probably the API has changed.